# New to ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Unable to configure app to use existing DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm totally new to ASP.NET Core 2.0; I created a new Project with In-App Authentication.

When I run the application and try the `Register` function, I get an error message saying that

> the table "AspNetUsers" does not exist.

That is OK and expected, I did not run the Migration scripts. For less confusion, I then deleted the Migration folder.

The problem I want to solve is I want the `Register` functions to register the user to my custom database. I already updated the settings in `appsettings.json` for this.

I made a Notepad++ search in the entire folder for `AspNetUsers` and found 0 hits. Yet, when I run the application again, the error message is the same, that `the table "AspNetUsers" does not exist.`

I am very confused. How does it know to look for that table if that text does not exist in the entire project directory?

How do I make it use my own database? I looked around, but I was unable to find any solutions. This is my last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: "I am very confused. How does it know to look for that table if that text does not exist in the entire project directory?" Of course it's not in your own project directory because you didn't write it. It's on the ASP.NET Core Identity framework. See its source code:  https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/f3ff51f1130d822700a621b5f5b19ef551d9a051/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUserContext.cs#L107

Comment: "How do I make it use my own database?" - Did you mean you want to use your own database to store identity stuff, i.e., users, roles, claims, etc? Or you just meant to rename those tables to whatever you want to call?